# Confused whether I need to follow up or not (Interview , Medical check up result)

Tags: communication, job-search, new-job, recruitment

So I am planning to work in one of the biggest banks in Indonesia, I already followed the recruitment process from online and offline test, HR interview, User interview, and I already cleared all of them.

The last step was Medical check up, I did Medical check up 2 weeks ago and the receptionist in the clinic said the result will be sent to company in maximum 2 working day's time.

So it seems that the company already have the result, but I still do not have any communication (call/email) whether I passed or not. I'm really confused, I want to follow-up with the recruitment team but it seems still so fast like 2 weeks. Shall I follow up?

My internship period almost end next week and I need to get the result asap before my internship period end (so I can decide whether I want to extend the internship or not).

Comment: I made some changes to the question to make it readable - please revert if something is unclear.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thankyou , it looks great , sry for my bad grammar

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR - Yes, you should follow up.

2 weeks is a long time. If the clinic said the report will be delivered by 2 working days, you should have made a check with the company about the receipt of the same by now (after 3-4 days).

Right now you are **assuming** things:

> *So it seems that the company already have the result.. But i still not have any offering , or call/email weather I pass or not pass the medical checkup.. I'm really confused..*

Don't do that. Get in touch with both clinic (whether the result was sent) and the company (about the application status).

Comment: Thankyou for the advice , i will try to follow up the result tomorrow